# Can not get Raspberry Pi to send UDP Datagram

Tags: raspbian, networking, node.js

Environment: Raspberry Pi 3; Raspbian Jessie (update/upgrade) today; coding in NodeJS (Javascript)

I do my development in Windows under Visual Studio 2015. The code works correctly there. The receivers all see the datagrams and Etherdetect (think wireshark) show the traffic as expected. When I move the code to the RPi the traffic never shows up on the LAN, Etherdetect sees nothing, the receivers see nothing.  The same nodejs environment is on the windows and RPi systems. The LAN is a single network.

The code looks like:

```
var message = new Buffer(data); 
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4'); 
client.send(message, 0, message.length, "192.168.1.255", 3639, function () {
         client.close();});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  It seems on the raspberry pi you need to bind the socket and setBroadcast true.  socket.bind(port,function() { socket.setBroadcast(true); socket.send( . . . . .

Comment: any chance you have a Git repo or anything so we can see the full code?